# Compress all the pictures to email size pixel (96)PPI by using command button

Tags: excel, vba, image, compression

I want to compress all the pictures in excel workbook to email size pixel 96( ppi) by using command button with the following code. But it doesn't work to compress all pictures .It can only compress 1 picture.

```
Sub test()

    Dim wsh As Worksheet

    Set wsh = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    wsh.Activate
    wsh.Shapes(1).Select

    SendKeys "%e", True
    SendKeys "~", True
    Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "PicturesCompress"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `For Each` loop to iterate through all shapes in the worksheet:

```
Sub test()

    Dim wsh As Worksheet
    Dim shp As Shape

    Set wsh = Worksheets("Sheet1")

    For Each shp In wsh.Shapes
        shp.Select
        SendKeys "%e", True
        SendKeys "~", True
        Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "PicturesCompress"
    Next shp

End Sub
```

Comment: I use for each loop from your code. Its really ok . But for the first time run this code it does not seem to work and cannot reduce pixel . After saving and close the file and reopen again and run this it seems work and reduce pixel at second time. Why this code work at second open time please suggest me

Comment: I have not been able to replicate this issue. I tested this by creating a new workbook, adding photos, then running the code. The photos compressed successfully. Maybe try restarting your computer? Also, did the issue only happen the first time you ran it or each time you use the macro?