# Compress all the pictures to email size (96)ppi by using command button

Tags: excel, vba

I use the following code to compress all the pictures in excel sheet to email size 96 ppi resolution .I think it seems does not work for the first time to compress the inserted pictures.I saved the xl sheet and open again the command button code works and compress the picture. Why the code is not working after inserting the pictures. It can work after closing the file and reopen time. 
Please advice for my problem.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim wsh As Worksheet
    Dim shp As Shape

    Set wsh = Worksheets("Photo")
    wsh.Activate
    For Each shp In wsh.Shapes
     shp.Select

        SendKeys "%e", True
        SendKeys "~", True
        Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "PicturesCompress"
    Next shp
End Sub
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62053028/compress-all-the-pictures-to-email-size-pixel-96ppi-by-using-command-button

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compress all the pictures to email size pixel (96)PPI by using command button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62053028/compress-all-the-pictures-to-email-size-pixel-96ppi-by-using-command-button)